# Ambiguity of personal pronouns

Tags: грамматика, местоимения

In the following verses by Boris Pasternak:

> Таким я вижу облик ваш и взгляд.
> Он мне внушен не тем столбом из соли,

from the poem [Анне Ахматовой](https://www.culture.ru/poems/13950/anne-akhmatovoi), I don't understand why we have "Он мне внушен" and not "Они мне внушены". Indeed, if "Он" refers to "облик ваш и взгляд", it should be a plural, right? If it refers either to "облик" or to "взгляд", how can we know to which one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Indeed, if "Он" refers to "облик ваш и взгляд", it should be a plural, right?

Generally speaking, yes.

There are some compound nouns, nominalized phrases that include the conjunction *и*, that effectively denote a single entity: *серп и молот, мать-и-мачеха, Тринидад и Тобаго*, etc. Grammatically speaking, they are singular nouns and govern the singular number in their dependent constituents. *Облик и взгляд* is not one of them.

Yet, enumerations that govern the singular are not unheard of, especially in poetry: *здоров ли отец мой и брат; и позабыл и волк, и волхв и лирник* etc.

> If it refers either to "облик" or to "взгляд", how can we know to which one?

Rosenthal et al., *Справочник по правописанию, произношению и литературному редактированию*, [§195.1](https://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliv-soglasovanie-opredeleniy-i-prilozheniy/ss-195-opredelenie-pri-sushchestvitelnyh-odnorodnyh-chlenah):

> Определение, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным — однородным членам, ставится в форме единственного числа:
>
> 1. если по смыслу сочетания ясно, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующим, например: *российская печать, радио и телевидение; развитие нашей техники, науки и культуры; создание новой оперы, балета, музыкальной комедии; литературный карьеризм и индивидуализм; школьная успеваемость и дисциплина, в своем изложении и выводах...; каждый завод и фабрика; уличный шум и грохот; летний жар и зной; морской прилив и отлив; различной формы и цвета*. Ср.: *необыкновенный шум и говор (Пушкин); Дикий гусь и утка прилетели первыми (Тургенев); общий веселый говор и хохот (Л. Толстой); написать свой адрес, имя, отчество (А.Н. Толстой); Ее великолепная шуба и шляпка не произвели никакого впечатления (Чехов).*

The examples given in support of this rule are, in my opinion, not quite relevant. The phrases *каждый завод и фабрика; развитие нашей техники, науки и культуры* etc. are cases of ellipsis; *её великолепная шуба и шляпка* is semantically dubious (it's not obvious that *великолепная* modifies *шляпка* as well, and if it does, *великолепные* would be stylistically better), and so on.

I would read this rule as "if you do have an enumeration modified by an adjective in the singular, this adjective modifies its every item, probably because of its copies being ellipsed".

That said, the text in your excerpt is a work of poetry by an author who's very big on metaphor and word play. It's not about conveying precise information in an unequivocal manner.